# Render SQL result in twig file

Tags: symfony, twig

How can i render result of following query in twig ?

```
$q = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT mark, student.studentName FROM DemoTemplateBundle:TblMarkDetails mark, DemoTemplateBundle:TblStudentDetails student
        WHERE student.id = mark.studentId'
);
$marks = $q->getArrayResult();
```

Table contents are

```
 Table tbl_mark_details                ||   tbl_student_details
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 id | student_id    | exam_id  | score ||   id | student name
 1  |1              | 1        |10     ||   1  | Student 1
 2  |2              | 1        |5      ||   2  | Student 2
 3  |2              | 2        |25     ||
```

I tried the following code, but no student name for the third row

```
{% set i=0 %}
{% for mark in marks %}
  {% if i%2 == 0 %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ mark.score  }}</td>
   <td>{{ mark.examId  }}</td>
  {% else %}
    <td>{{ mark.studentName  }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% set i = i+1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Vishnu V

Comment: Just as a sidenote u can use `loop.index`to determine the index rather than using `i` also u can test for even with : {% if loop.index is even %} or use the isdivisbleby(2) test (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/divisibleby.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your should try like this :

```
    $q = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT mark, student FROM DemoTemplateBundle:TblMarkDetails mark,     DemoTemplateBundle:TblStudentDetails student
    WHERE student.id = mark.studentId'
    );
    $marks = $q->getResult();
```

and your twig is all right ..